# Alexa Skills: AudioPlayer HLS stream URL not working

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am using the "AudioPlayer" of the "Alexa Skill Kit" to stream an HLS audio format URL. I am receiving no errors from the AWS Lambda and from the Developer Portal. I am testing by using the Silent Echo (https://silentecho.bespoken.io/). Alexa is able to play MP3 formatted URLs, and some HLS I found through the forum. However, my HLS URL is not working.

My HLS URL: http://cpdc101-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ISNCPDCMB1_1@314337/master.m3u8

Other HLS URL: https://as-hls-ww-live.bbcfmt.hs.llnwd.net/pool_6/live/bbc_radio_fourfm/bbc_radio_fourfm.isml/bbc_radio_fourfm-audio%3d96000.norewind.m3u8

The other HLS URL is playing, but I don't hear anything. Nonetheless, their's work while my HLS with Silent Echo comes up with this error "there was a problem with the requested skills response." Does anyone see the difference between my HLS link and their's?

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this HLS URL to work?

The code:

```js
var lastPlayedByUser = {};
var streamURL = "http://cpdc101-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ISNCPDCMB1_1@314337/master.m3u8";


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var player = new SidRothPlayer(event, context);
    player.handle();
};

var SidRothPlayer = function (event, context) {
    this.event = event;
    this.context = context;
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.handle = function () {
    var requestType = this.event.request.type;
    var userId = this.event.context ? this.event.context.System.user.userId : this.event.session.user.userId;

   if (requestType === "LaunchRequest") {
        this.play(streamURL, 0);

    } else  if (requestType === "IntentRequest") {
        var intent = this.event.request.intent;
        if (intent.name === "Play") {
            this.play(streamURL, 0);

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.PauseIntent") {
            this.stop();

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.ResumeIntent") {
            var lastPlayed = this.loadLastPlayed(userId);
            var offsetInMilliseconds = 0;
            if (lastPlayed !== null) {
                offsetInMilliseconds = lastPlayed.request.offsetInMilliseconds;
            }

            this.play(streamURL, offsetInMilliseconds);
        }
    } else if (requestType === "AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped") {
        this.saveLastPlayed(userId, this.event);
        this.context.succeed(true);
    }
};


 SidRothPlayer.prototype.play = function (audioURL, offsetInMilliseconds) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Play",
                    playBehavior: "REPLACE_ALL", 
                    audioItem: {
                        stream: {
                            url: audioURL,
                            token: "0", 
                            expectedPreviousToken: null, 
                            offsetInMilliseconds: offsetInMilliseconds
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};


SidRothPlayer.prototype.stop = function () {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Stop"
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.saveLastPlayed = function (userId, lastPlayed) {
    lastPlayedByUser[userId] = lastPlayed;
};

SidRothPlayer.prototype.loadLastPlayed = function (userId) {
    var lastPlayed = null;
    if (userId in lastPlayedByUser) {
        lastPlayed = lastPlayedByUser[userId];
    }
    return lastPlayed;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

your stream url should be  https .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  Wejd DAGHFOUS. I changed the URL to HTTPS and the error went away! I can play it now, however like the other HLS links, I can't hear anything.

Thank you  joseluismg. Do you know if the HLS must be only Audio to play?

Comment: I just tested other HLS which I believe are audio only. They are radio stations. Worked in VLC, however it isn't being played on my Silent Echo.

Other HLS:


- https://c4.prod.playlists.ihrhls.com/3379/playlist.m3u8


- http://radioitaliasmi-lh.akamaihd.net/i/radioitaliasmi_1@329643/master.m3u8


- http://radiom2o-lh.akamaihd.net/i/RadioM2o_Live_1@42518/master.m3u8

Comment: The correct way is to just make the URL into HTTPS. Super simple answer, Thank you Wejd.